# MySql: table index speed vs consecutive row speed. Is there a big difference?

Tags: mysql, database, select, indexing

I have a table `UserRecord` which has columns `id, userId, recordType, recordCount`, with INDEX on `userId` and auto-incrementing `id`. The table is to record different user behaviors and count the number of times of the behavior.

The create table looks like following:
(Edit: I am not allowed to change the table structure due to project limitation)

```
CREATE TABLE `UserRecord` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
    `userId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `recordType` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `recordCount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `userId` (`userId`)
);
```

I know in advance that there are 10 recordTypes (behavior types) in total, but some user behaviors are very unlikely so some users might not ever perform once such behavior. I am wondering whether I should generate all the 10 rows whenever a new user is created in order for the rows to have consecutive `id`s, or insert a record whenever it is first touched.

Method 1: I generate all the 10 rows when a new user is created, so the table size is always going to be 10 times the number of users, but every single user will have their records with consecutive `id`s.

Method 2: I generate a record only when a user first perform the recordType behavior. In this way the table on average will have size around 3 times the number of users, but records for the same user (of different types) might have `id`s very different, like 10000 and 1000000.

Now consider when I select the following query on a large scale:

```
select * from UserRecord where userId=x;
```

Remainder: `userId` has an INDEX on it. My question is, will the first method be significantly faster than the second, or not?

I would like to understand this from a theoretical aspect rather than experimental result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two tables:

- table with one row per user.  This probably has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY`
- table with one row per behavior per user.  (Up to 10 times as many rows)  `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, behavior)`

This gives the rows (up to 10) for user number 123:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM Users
    JOIN Behaviors  USING(user_id)
    WHERE user_id = 123
```

A `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` can provide a row of NULLs when you hit a missing behavior.

A `PRIMARY KEY` is an index and is "unique".

Unless your list of users includes everyone in a large country, I would not worry about performance.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and tentative queries.

**Locality of reference**

The data in the table is in `PRIMARY KEY` order.

If the [up to] 10 rows for one `user_id` are inserted as [up to] 10 single-row inserts, then the rows will *probably* have consecutive `ids` (hence, adjacent in the BTree).  At least they will have "close" ids.

If a user's rows are inserted as a multi-row ("batch") `INSERT`, then the rows *will* be adjacent.  Also, such an insert will be on the order of 3 times as fast.

This forces ordering, eliminates a column, etc:

```
CREATE TABLE `UserRecord` (
    `userId` INT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `recordType` TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `recordCount` INT unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`, recordType)
);
```

And it cuts the disk space about in half.

By not going through a secondary key, `SELECT ... WHERE userId = 1000` will be faster.

Again, batch `INSERT` is preferred for speed.

Even if you *later* add a row for a Type because its number is no longer zero, it will be "adjacent" to the other columns for the user.  Hence, the `SELECT ... WHERE userId = 1000` continues to be fast.

I recommend

```
INSERT INTO t
    (userId, recordType, recordCount)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        recordCount = VALUES(recordCount) + 1;
```

This takes care of the `INSERT` when it goes from 0 to 1 *and* takes care of incrementing by 1.

**compare Methods 1 and 2**

This may get into an analysis of disk activity and caching, so can you provide:

- RAM size
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
- the current number of rows in the table
- the current table size (in GB)
- the anticipated number of rows when the table reaches its max
- the various queries (INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT)
- the relative frequency of those queries.

The analysis will go something like this:

- Method 1 (repopulate with 10 rows per) -- bulkier, thereby more likely to be bigger than cache, thereby slower due to more I/O.  OTOH, fetching the 10 will not take more I/O since they are clustered together.
- Method 2 (the 10 are scattered, but not empty) -- smaller table, hence better caching.  But `SELECTing` the 10 may need up to 10 disk hits.
- Method 3 (my table and index improvements) -- better than both 1 and 2.

If it turns out that the table will never be bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (and there are no other big tables vying for cache space), then Method 1 is not worth doing.

Otherwise, the relative frequency of the queries will determine which of Method 1 or 2 will be faster on average.

Method 3 always wins.

**Analysis**

Assuming

- 10M rows --> less than 1 GB for the table+indexes for any Method.
- A cloud instance of at least 4GB --> The table will probably stay completely cached.  --> very little I/O.

Conclusion

Methods 1 and 2 won't show much overall performance difference.  The operations you mentioned will each take very few milliseconds for either Method.

Comment: I have added the create table in the scenario. I am only considering the performance of the query "select * from UserRecord where userId=1000" for this table and there is no other table in consideration. I am considering scale of millions of people with tens of millions of records, assuming every user can have up to 10 records (one for each type).

Comment: In addition the select needs to be performed on a repeated automatic basis for analysis so performance does matter. The insertion are also done automatically and my question was should we insert all 10 records at once which takes more space but guarantees the primary keys are next to each other for the same user, or should we insert a record only when the a valid count occurs, which will make the rows for the same user very far apart in terms of primary key (although we have the userId index).

Comment: @cr001 - See what I added; I think it addresses your various concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am sorry I did not express clearly enough but what I would like to know is the comparison of the two methods available(theoretical), rather than hoping for a third solution. I understand your solution might be the fastest but there are many limitations in my project (including sharing data structure with a client software) which makes it not feasible. There are other drawbacks for the "batch insert" way such as increased data transfer over to the client software, meaning more expensive internet cost. What I want to know is only how method1 compares to method2.

Comment: To be clearer, my current mind set is that I will choose method 1 if it runs at least 1.5 times faster than method 2 on any large scale. Otherwise I will choose method 2. In other words if the big O notation speed of the two are the same and the constant difference is not more than 1.5 I will tend to choose method 2 for its other benifits.

Comment: I also understand that from an expert's viewpoint the reason for not using the compound primary key solution might not be convincing enough but there are other internal limitations in my company which I cannot post online and I hope you understand that I have only the two solutions I posted in the question to choose from.

Comment: @cr001 - OK, I added a section on that.

Comment: Thank you for the update. The hardware is assumed to be a cloud server, but not determined yet (probably will be of the same category as google cloud platform) so I am not able to give sufficient information on that but what I can provide is: (1) number of rows will be at least a million and there is no upper limit (probably will stop at somewhere around 5-10 million). (2) The ratio of Select : Update/Insert will be around 7:3. Is it possible to predict whether method 1 will be at least 1.5 times faster than method 2 or not, or does it really depends heavily on the hardware?

Comment: For the method 3 part, I do appreciate that it is the best method based on what I provided, but in fact this is not even the real table and I completely made it up for demonstrating the core problem (the real table cannot be provided for confidential reason). And there are other limitations as well so I really can only choose from the two methods.

Comment: @cr001 - I added another section.  A big performance problem for RE is in searching.  I have addressed that problem a few times; search for my replies in stackoverflow and maybe dba.stackexchange.  The gist is to have columns for 'price' and 'bedrooms', but leave 'gazebo' in a JSON string for the app to check.  Still not very efficient.  Maybe someday I will think of a better way and write a blog.